# Denoting a timeout for socket functions, Python

Tags: python, sockets, timeout

I'm working on a script that takes a list of domains and/or IPs and does a bunch of stuff with them.

The problem I'm having is that I need both the IP and Domain, if possible, so when I get an IP, I attempt to resolve it to a host, via gethostbyaddr(), and vice versa for when I get a domain via gethostbyname().

These functions hang for some time, however if they are unable to resolve, which bogs my script down quite a bit. All I want to do is if the name/address can't be resolved right away, ignore it and move to the next. I've seen some other answers on here but none of them seems to be what I need. One seems to only work with UNIX (I'm on Windows), and others seem to be terminating the entire script if the host can't be resolved. I just want to move to the next one.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there isn't a great cross platform solution for setting timeouts with gethostbyname and gethostbyaddr in python.

You can wrap the gethostbyname calls in a Process with multiprocessing.Process and then join the process for a few seconds.

```
def resolve(host, ret):
    ret['val'] = socket.gethostbyname(host)


for host in hostnames_to_resolve:
    manager = Manager()
    return_data = manager.dict()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=resolve, args=(host,return_data))
    p.start()
    p.join(2) # 2 second timeout

    if p.is_alive():
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
    else:
        print return_data['val'] # the result of the gethostbyname call
```